# Can anybody explain a logic behind the construction get + gerund?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

I want to understand the logiс behind such construction as "get + (verb + ing)". I know, it means "to start some action", but I want to get clearer why. Gerund means mostly something like "to be in the state of some process", get in its core means "change of state". Maybe there is some good explanation to understand its nature?

Comment: Yes, _get_ as in _get dressed, get well_ etc refers to a change of state, so _get moving_ = put yourself into the state of being in motion.

Comment: Your question seems to contain the answer. Gerunds mean 'state of some process',  get indicates "change state" so get + V-ing means "change state", or "start an action".  However it is mostly restricted to idioms, and idioms don't need to follow any particular logic.

Comment: @JamesK, Thanks for your reply, but could you please explain deeper what you mean saying "it is mostly restricted to idioms"?

Comment: I mean there are idiomatic expressions like "get moving", "get going".  They are idiomatic because "get moving" doesn't just mean "start to move" but something like "Stop laying in on the sofa!" (in context). It is rather rare to use this construction with random verbs.  I would not say "Please get playing football"

Comment: Great, can you write an answer?

Comment: @JamesK, ok, sure

Answer (score 2):

The construction "get + (verb + ing)" implies a change of state or starting an action, and it is mostly used in idiomatic expressions. The gerund in this construction means "state of some process," while "get" indicates a change of state. Therefore, "get + V-ing" means "change state" or "start an action." However, it is uncommon to use this construction with random verbs. Expressions such as "get moving" and "get going" are idiomatic as they convey more than just starting an action. For instance, "get moving" can imply "stop being idle", but using it with random verbs is uncommon. "Please get playing football" would not be typical.

Answer (score 0):

get+going
get+moving
get+working

get + verbING **means** **start** moving, start going, start working.